# Problem with Flash size on ESP8266-01S on VSCode (PlatformIO)

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, esp8266, platformio

I have a problem with programing my ESP8266-01S with PlatformIO on VSCode. Actually, it is working well on Arduino, but I would like to use VSCode because it is more comfortable (and it is not working on VSCode !).
I've noticed a difference in the terminal when I upload my code between the two softwares. Let me show you :

This is what I get on Arduino :

```
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM16
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: ec:fa:bc:27:2d:0a
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 1MB
Compressed 265056 bytes to 195069...
Writing at 0x00000000... (8 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (16 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (25 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (33 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (41 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (50 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (58 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (66 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (75 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (83 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (91 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (100 %)
Wrote 265056 bytes (195069 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 19.9 seconds (effective 106.3 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

And this is what I get on VSCode :

```
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM16
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: ec:fa:bc:27:2d:0a
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Compressed 265056 bytes to 195047...
Writing at 0x00000000... (8 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (16 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (25 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (33 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (41 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (50 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (58 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (66 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (75 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (83 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (91 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (100 %)
Wrote 265056 bytes (195047 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 20.0 seconds (effective 106.2 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Soft resetting...
```

You can see there is a difference with the resetting (but I've seen that it wasn't an issue), and there is also a difference with the "Auto-detected Flash size: 1MB" on Arduino which we don't have on VSCode. I don't know if it is a real issue ...

Maybe you can help me ... Thank you very much !!

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having with ESP and PlatformIO?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear enough ... The observed problem is that I try to upload my code with VSCode/PlatformIO, the board "react" well when I do so (built in led toggle a little), but then it is like I haven't upload any code on it (my code is not executing) ... It is just a simple code (toggle the built in led). But this is working well on Arduino ... I hope you will understand ... thank you very much

Comment: I asked because I'm not convinced the problem is related to flash size, or anything else shown in the two logs from your question. Have you tried pressing the Reset button on the ESP board after flashing is finished? Can you show us your `platformio.ini` contents? And which specific board are you selecting in Arduino IDE when the code works?

Comment: As it is an ESP8266-01S board, there is no reset button (I use a CH340 programer, and connect the GPIO0 and GND together to enter flash mode, but all my hardware procedure should be ok as it is working on Arduino). The following is my "platformio.ini" file :
`[env:esp01_1m]
platform = espressif8266
board = esp01_1m
framework = arduino
` And finally I choose the _Espressif Generic ESP8266 ESP-01 1M_ board on PlatformIO, and the _Generic ESP8266 Module_ board on Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has nothing to do with flash memory size from the comments you provided.

If your setup on Arduino IDE is `Generic ESP8266 Module` and it is working, it means that the `LED_BUILTIN` is configured at GPIO1 as shown in the [source code](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/variants/generic/pins_arduino.h#L36) of ESP8266 core for Arduino.

This means that you had an EPS-01 instead of an ESP-01S. One of the differences between ESP-01 and ESP-01S is that the `LED_BUILTIN` is wired to the different GPIO pin. ESP-01 has the `LED_BUILTIN` wired to GPIO1, while ESP-01S has the `LED_BUILTIN` wired to GPIO2.

This [picture](https://github.com/e-tinkers/better-way-to-use-esp-01/blob/master/images/ESP-01_versus_ESP-01S.jpg) shows the different between ESP-01 and ESP-01S, visually ESP-01 has 2 LEDs on board near the antenna, while ESP-01S have two extra resistor between header pins and ESP8266EX chip, and with only one LED near the antenna.

**Easier way to fix it**

The easier way to address it is to define your own pin assignment instead of using pre-defined `LED_BUILTIN`.

```
#define LED 2

void setup(){
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  // other codes
}
```

In case of ESP-01, you could also select a board that has LED_BUILTIN defined as 2. For example, [d1 mini](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/variants/d1_mini/pins_arduino.h#L35) which is based on ESP-12 pinout but should works for ESP-01 as well.

Comment: I wasn't aware about this difference. So now it is working well with my ESP-01S on GPIO2 (it is not working with `LED_BUILTIN` on PlatformIO, but I won't complain ! `LED_BUILTIN` is working on Arduino ...). But it is still not working with my ESP-01 new version (1MB flash) ... But at least, something works on PlatformIO, there are some improvement ! Thank you very much ! Any idea about the ESP-01 new version ? (Everything is working fine on Arduino for this board too)

Comment: I understood why `LED_BUILTIN` is not working on PlatformIO : when I put my mouse on it I read in the information box `#define LED_BUILTIN 1`. It is normal that on ESP-01S it is not working as the internal led is wired on GPIO2 as you said. Do you know where is the file where I could change this ? It is not a big issue, the fact that the ESP-01 new version doesn't work on PlatformIO is a bigger problem to me.

Comment: I updated my answer on how to fix it. Please take a look. BTW, if this answer your question, appreciated that you could accept it as the answer by click on the tick or upvote it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I had the idea of doing this, but I find a bit too easy : it is not solving the problem in the end ... And the ESP-01 still doesn't work. But you found my problem with the ESP-01S so I can consider the problem is solved. But if anyone know why the ESP-01 doesn't work on PlatformIO, I will be happy to discuss it with you.